# Radio Button Checked Listener With Alert Box

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog, radio-group

I want an alert box to appear when the radio button is clicked.
When `yes` is selected, set the check and if not selected, unset the check.

I tried this code using radio group CheckedChangeListener & alert dialog.

```
 public void onRadioButtonChecked() {
    Log.v(TAG,"Radio Button : ");
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int buttonId) {
            // Check which radio button was clicked
            Log.v(TAG,"on checked: value" + radioGroup+" radio "+buttonId);
            switch(buttonId) {
                case R.id.radioButton:
                    Log.v(TAG,"radio button1 : ");
                    openDefault();
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton2:
                    Log.v(TAG,"radio button2 : ");
                    openCalendar();
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton3:
                    Log.v(TAG,"radio button3 : ");
                    openCustom();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void openDefault(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to enable Default settings? ");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                            radiobutton1.setChecked(true);
                            onRadioButtonChecked();
                            mOutputText.setText("Default Settings\n");
                            DefaultAlert();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Default Settings Enabled",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                            radiobutton1.setChecked(false);
                            onRadioButtonChecked();
                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void openCalendar(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to enable Google calendar settings? ");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                    radiobutton2.setChecked(true);
                    onRadioButtonChecked();
                    mOutputText.setText("");
                    getResultsFromApi();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Calendar Settings Enabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                    radiobutton2.setChecked(false);
                    onRadioButtonChecked();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void openCustom(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to enable Custom settings? ");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                    radiobutton3.setChecked(true);
                    onRadioButtonChecked();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Custom Settings Enabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                    radiobutton3.setChecked(false);
                    onRadioButtonChecked();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

If i radio button check it's appear alert box and when i press "No" it will uncheck. and go to the same radio again and press "yes" from the alert box it will not check but the Toast will appear.

What is the issue and give a solution.

Thank You

Comment: what do you mean by not working ??? app crash ?? if yes then paste log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will help you.!  All you need is radiogroup `clearcheck()` method.

Let me tell first what issue in your code. When you select no from alert dialog box effect of this two line

> radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
>   radiobutton1.setChecked(false);

check changes cannot listening by radiogroup. So radiogroup holds the checkchanges defaulty means it holds true or false depends upon checked state. It cannot hold the reference from your code while listener is null at that case.

To avoid this issue,you need to remove this line

> radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

But this will cause your dialog open repeatedly. So Here you have solution with the help of `clearcheck` method. Try below code

```
public void onRadioButtonChecked() {
    Log.v("","Radio Button : ");
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int buttonId) {
            // Check which radio button was clicked
            Log.v("","on checked: value" + radioGroup+" radio "+buttonId);
            switch(buttonId) {

                case R.id.radioButton1:
                    Log.v("","radio button1 : ");
                    if(radiobutton1.isChecked())
                    {
                        openDefault();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton2:
                    Log.v("","radio button2 : ");

                    if(radiobutton2.isChecked()) {
                        openCalendar();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton3:
                    Log.v("","radio button3 : ");

                    if(radiobutton3.isChecked()) {
                        openCustom();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}



public void openDefault(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to enable Default settings? ");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Default Settings Enabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    radioGroup.clearCheck();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void openCalendar(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to enable Google calendar settings? ");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Calendar Settings Enabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    radioGroup.clearCheck();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void openCustom(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to enable Custom settings? ");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Custom Settings Enabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    radioGroup.clearCheck();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Simply empty your **YES** condition its automatically select radiobutton by default. Add radiogroup clearcheck in **NO** condition. And also clearcheck call changelistener again so to avoid that i checked condition isChecked() of button to show dialog.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you are making mistake because here you need the choice, not the option so please replace your radio button with the checkbox.

Or the solution for open dialog register click listener with the checkbox or now as radio button its good for open your dialog.

Replace your bellow code with below my code

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int buttonId) {
                // Check which radio button was clicked
                Log.v(TAG,"on checked: value" + radioGroup+" radio "+buttonId);
                switch(buttonId) {
                    case R.id.radioButton:
                        Log.v(TAG,"radio button1 : ");
                        openDefault();
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton2:
                        Log.v(TAG,"radio button2 : ");
                        openCalendar();
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton3:
                        Log.v(TAG,"radio button3 : ");
                        openCustom();
                }
            }
        });
```

My Code

```
radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDefault();
            }
        });
        radioButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openCalendar();
            }
        });
        radioButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openCustom();
            }
        });
```

Comment: But i want only one to select. if i used checkbox it can be multiple to select. isn't?

Comment: Okay then put as it is and just open dialog using click listener it will work.

Comment: That mean inside the switch case, without calling directly alert dialog open function add a click listener inside the switch case to call the alert dialog open function. is that?